# How are stock market gains treated within an inherited IRA (when I eventually distribute)?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, income-tax, ira

I inherited my mother's inheritable IRA in 2011; present value $200k. I'm now 60.

I've been buying and selling mutual funds within the IRA, making a little profit, and also buying a specific stock.

If the stock hits really big this year, I want to sell it and distribute it from the IRA.
Will it be taxed as ordinary income?